# VBA: Finding a date

Tags: vba, date

I want to find a date in a range, or rather part of a date. For example, I have the month and the year from a user input, stored in two variables `userInputMonth` and `userInputYear`, and would now like to find out in which row they appear.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckDate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim userInputYear As String
    Dim userInputMonth As String
    Dim rngDate As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(2)
    userInputYear = Right(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value, 4) 'e.g. "2019"
    userInputMonth = Mid(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value, 2, 2) 'e.g. "09"

    Set rngDate = ws.Range("A3:A11")
    Set foundCell = rngDate.Find("??." & userInputMonth & "." & userInputYear)
    Debug.Print foundCell.Row '-> error


   '=====Trying out stuff=====
   Set foundCell = rngDate.Find(userInputMonth)
   Debug.Print foundCell.Row 'works
   Set foundCell = rngDate.Find(userInputMonth & ".")
   Debug.Print foundCell.Row '-> error
   Set foundCell = rngDate.Find("12.2019")
   Debug.Print foundCell.Row '-> error

End Sub
```

I guess the format is the problem, but how do I deal with this, but I don't know how to apply something like `CStr` to this issue

edit: The data in `rngDate` looks like this: 31.12.2019 (formatted as date). `A1` is text (e.g. A12 2019).

Comment: It is hard working with dates like this. Do you only have one date per month?

Comment: @Damian It's quarterly data, so four dates per year. In the Excel file I have to work with (and where I want to find the row number) each quarter is written out with the last day of the quarter, i.e. 31.12.2019, 30.09.2019, 30.06.2019 etc. If it's too difficult, I might be able to force the user input to be of the same format, but I'm not sure how much I'd have to change in the sheet and the already existing code (that I haven't written)

Comment: Are your dates are actual dates in Excel? You might have more luck creating an actual date and looking for that, rather than the textual representation of a date. 

MS have some docs here. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: @RichardCrossley Judging from the yours and Damian's response, I can get an idea how complicated dates can be. So creating a date sounds like a goo workaround.

Comment: Dates (and times) in Excel are implemented as floating point numbers. The date part is the "whole number" and the time is the fractional part of the date. It makes sense if you think about. 8am nnnnn.33333333 because it's 1/3rd of the way through the day.

Comment: You can use your date as you try, only using `userInputMonth = Mid(CStr(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value), 2, 2)`! Excel keeps date in cells as numbers... You must force it to let you read a string. But, if it is well formatted you only need to use `Day(wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value)`...

Comment: @Alex I Would use `DateSerial(Year, Monht, LastDay)` and find that date, because it will always be the last day of that month.

Comment: @Damian That's how I'm gonna do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have to decide which type of data you want to manipulate. Do you prefer working with dates or strings ? After that choice, it will be easier to determine which operations will be necessary and which method or function will be applicable (you cannot do the same thing with dates or strings). Cheers